# Why is this preorder traversal returning the last nodes?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, binary-tree, preorder

I understand why the letters [A, B, D] are appended to the list. But I don't understand how the last two letters [E, C] gets added.
After pre_order('C', nodes), the letter 'C' has no left child, how can the function know to go one step up to letter 'B' and checks its children, and so on? See the tree image:
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsNJP.png)

```
def pre_order(root, nodes):
    nodes.append(root.data)
    if root and root.left:
        pre_order(root.left, nodes)
    if root and root.right:
        pre_order(root.right, nodes)
    return nodes

    print(pre_order(root, [])) #prints ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'C']
```

Comment: Google recurency and preorder. When something doesn't have children or the children were already checked, the function returns and whatever function executed it, continues.

Comment: @h4z3, it doesn't continue with whatever function that executed it. After the letter 'D', it calls the function with the letter 'E'. Why?

Comment: Yes, it does continue - but it was the same function (with different arguments) that executed it. That's what recursion is (sorry for my mistake earlier, I transliterated instead of translating).

Comment: @GoldenRetriever That's how you traverse a tree in pre-order.

Answer (score 0):

After execution, function returns to a whatever place called it, in this case - the call to the same function but with different arguments.

Let's see how it works in your example. Each indent is a new execution - look how we return to the previous indent and continue.

- we start with pre_order on node A with empty list

  - append A to the current list, new list = [A]
  - first `if` hits, so we execute on B with the list:

    - append B to the current list [A], new list = [A, B]
    - first `if` hits, so we execute on D with the list:

      - append D to the current list [A, B], new list = [A, B, D]
      - first `if` doesn't hit because D doesn't have a left child
      - second `if` doesn't hit because D doesn't have a right child
      - return [A, B, D]
    - we got the result of the inner execution and continue where it was started (in B)
    - second `if` hits, so we execute on E with the list (now changed in the inner function, thanks to mutability)

      - append E to the current list [A, B, D], new list = [A, B, D, E]
      - first `if` doesn't hit because E doesn't have a left child
      - second `if` doesn't hit because E doesn't have a right child
      - return [A, B, D, E]
    - we got the result of the inner execution and continue where it was started (in B)
    - return [A, B, D, E]
  - we got the result of the inner execution and continue where it was started (in A)
  - second `if` hits, so we execute on C with the list (now changed multiple times in inner executions)

    - append C to the current list [A, B, D, E], new list = [A, B, D, E, C]
    - first `if` doesn't hit because C doesn't have a left child
    - second `if` doesn't hit because C doesn't have a right child
    - return [A, B, D, E, C]
  - we got the result of the inner execution and continue where it was started (in A)
  - return [A, B, D, E, C]
- we get back to where we first executed pre_order - that is, a print function

[There might be slight typos and small mistakes in the list, I copy-pasted most things and it's possible I forgot about changing something]

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed description. However, when the function gets called with the same argument that called it in the first place, how is it that it's not running in an infinite loop? Because, lets say it gets called with B again, whats keeping it from visiting the left child of B again?

Comment: It returns to the call, not to the beginning of the function. Basically, you get literally to the same line (if you number them, then it's easier to imagine) but after the execution. Just like `x =  len(range(10)) + 1` will first go into `range(10)` and create it and return where it was called, then `len` executes and returns where it was called, then `+` executes and returns, then `x` gets assigned. `10+1` doesn't care how it got that `10` (`len`), neither it cares what happens with its result (`x=`).

Comment: The previous state is stored so that program knows where it needs to continue. It's stored on a special stack and "Stack Overflow" is an exception that is raised when you get too many calls (e.g. too long or infinite recursion) and you don't have place to store the previous state anymore.